# Как скопилировать все несвязные файлы в Go?

Tags: golang, компиляция

У меня есть небольшое количество несвязных между собой файлов (это не части модуля или проекта), просто разного рода наброски и заметки.

Как собрать их все разом явно не указывая каждый раз, что именно нужно скомпилировать?

```
go run .
# _/mnt/library/projects/hck/Go
./listen.go:12:6: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./array.go:7:6
```

```
go build .
# _/home/Sharlatan/Projects/hck/Go
./listen.go:12:6: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ./array.go:7:6
```

*/array.go/*

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a1 [10]int
    a2 := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2)
}
```

*/listen.go/*

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

Comment: баш/бат скрипт написать или через Makefile. Перебираешь директории и компилишь

Comment: @Axifive ну это ясно, я больше интересуюсь про builtin функционал.

Comment: По правильному каждый пакет должен быть в отдельном каталоге, и соответственно на пакет только одно объявление main метода.
Вот тут есть рекомендации по организации проектов: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо указывать каждый файл по отдельности. Если вы хотите это
автоматизировать, используйте *Make*:

```make
all: array.bin listen.bin
array.bin:  ; go build -o $@ ./array.go
listen.bin: ; go build -o $@ ./listen.go
```

Или *Shell*:

```sh
for f in ./array.go ./listen.go
do
	go build -o "${f%.go}.bin" "$f"
done
```

Comment: В таком случае, что пытается сделать `go run .` или `go build .`?

Comment: @Hellseher Я не конца понимаю ваш вопрос.  Если вы хотите таким же образом делать `go run`, просто замените команду `go build` и её флаги на нужные.

Answer (score 0):

Точка (.) в конце команды говорит о том, что все принадлежит одному пакету и выдает ошибку о дублированной `main()` при компиляции.

Старый добрый `Makefile` (GNU make) может решить "проблему" там, где ее вроде и не должно быть - скомпилировать заведомо неизвестный список несвязных между собой файлов.

/Makefile/

```
GO_FILES := $(wildcard ./*.go)

all:
    @$(foreach file ,$(GO_FILES), go build -o $(subst .go,,$(file)) $(file);)
```

```
ls; make; ls 
Makefile  array.go  listen.go  randomPass.go
Makefile  array  array.go  listen  listen.go  randomPass  randomPass.g
```

**Ссылки**

- https://getstream.io/blog/how-a-go-program-compiles-down-to-machine-code/
- https://github.com/golang `go/src/go/` базовые компоненты `scanner` `token` `parser` `ast`